# De acuerdo a una palabra que contenga la columna del DataFrame, realizar cierta acción

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo el siguiente código:

```
pronostico = ['D) Pronóstico'] 
stock = ['E) Stock Proyectado']

if df4[df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)]:
     f2 = df4["S28-16/07/2021"] /  df4["Factor"]
     df4['Dispo Inicial Directas D+2'] = f2
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si contiene la palabra "D) Pronóstico" en la columna VALORES este proceda hacer la división del `if` como se puede observar, pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy  
  self._set_item(key, value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\espon\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python\Balances.py", line 64, in <module>
    if df4[df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)]:
  File "C:\Users\espon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: es muy difícil poner el resultado de un filtro en una condición ;)

Comment: Al hacer `df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)` obtienes una matriz de booleanos y si haces `df[df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)]` obtienes solo los valores `True` de la matriz de booleanos. Te dice que es ambiguo por que no sabe a que te estas refiriendo realmente, puedes usar `any()` o cualquiera de los métodos que te recomienda. Sin mayores detalles de lo que quieres hacer, es lo único que puedo decir

Answer (score 0):

El `if` es un bloque de control escalar, es decir evalúa una sola condición lógica y `df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)` tiene eventualmente múltiples valores lógicos. Lo que necesitarías es usar en todo caso una condición vectorial como [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)`

```
df4['Dispo Inicial Directas D+2'] = np.where(df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico), 
                                             df4["S28-16/07/2021"] / df4["Factor"], 
                                             df4['Dispo Inicial Directas D+2'])
```

Las líneas adicionales son solo para darle legibilidad a la condición, conceptualmente es un `if .. else ..`, se retorna un valor en caso de `True` y otro valor en caso contrario.

Otra forma, sin usar un condicional, es afectar únicamente los valores de la selección original:

```
seleccion = df4[df4.VALORES.isin(pronostico)]
df4.loc[seleccion,'Dispo Inicial Directas D+2'] = df4[seleccion]['S28-16/07/2021'] / df4[seleccion]['Factor']
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una aplicacion lambda para hacer el llamado a una funcion y definir tu validacion en la funcion

```
def validation(row):
    result = ''

    if row['valores'] in pronostico:
        result = row["S28-16/07/2021"] / row["Factor"]

    return result
```

y para hacer la validacion para cada row aplicamos el lambda

```
df4['Dispo Inicial Directas D+2'] = df4.apply(lambda x: validation(x), axis=1)
```